# Loading database driven variable data as variables in AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I am attempting to have a list populated through a database(working) bring you to a nested(might be the wrong word) page within your current page using AJAX and PHP.  My problem is one with PHP not AJAX as far as I am aware.  I have sql injection protection already coded in.  I believe the problem is entirely located in the getrss.php around line 24.  I am receiving no errors.

Many thanks!

rss.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showRSS(str) {
if (str.length==0) {
document.getElementById("rssOutput").innerHTML="";
return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {  // code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
  document.getElementById("rssOutput").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getrss.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>


<form method="post" action="rss.php">
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","table");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM rssfeeds");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['rssfeedname'] . "</option>";
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="rssOutput">RSS Display</div>
</body>
</html>
```

getrss.php

```
<?php
//get the q parameter from URL
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","table");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id ='".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);


?>


<?php 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

$info2 = $row['info2'];
$id = $row['id'];
}
?>

<?php
// escape variables for security
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['id']);
$info2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['info2']);


//find out which feed was selected
if($q=='" . $row['id'] . "') {
$xml=('" . $row['info2'] . "');
}


$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);

//get elements from "<channel>"
$channel=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);
$channel_title = $channel->getElementsByTagName('title')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_link = $channel->getElementsByTagName('link')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_desc = $channel->getElementsByTagName('description')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

//output elements from "<channel>"
echo("<p><a href='" . $channel_link . "'>" . $channel_title . "</a>");
echo("<br>");
echo($channel_desc . "</p>");

//get and output "<item>" elements
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');
for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++) {
$item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$item_link=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$item_desc=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo ("<p><a href='" . $item_link . "'>" . $item_title . "</a>");
echo ("<br>");
echo ($item_desc . "</p>");
}
?>
```

Comment: I would swap out that mysqli_* code for PDO, just to be safe. because afaik you cant 100% trust mysqli_real_escape_string ( might be wrong here.. ) So if i were you, i would go with PDO, after that generate your html. You should only echo things out in the end, to make the script faster.  If i were you, i would swap out that ajax code for jQuery ajax calls ( jquery is cross-browser and tested ).

Comment: There are no line numbers in SO, which is the line you're having a problem with?

Comment: So you don't know what error are you getting? Let PHP do it for you! insert `ini_set("display_errors",1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` in top of your PHP file.

Comment: You have quoting problems on the `if($q==` and `$xml=` lines. You should be getting parse errors for that, aren't you?

Comment: @Barmar   Yes, that is where I believe I am having the problem but I am receiving no errors.  This could be in part due to it being a nested page(not sure if this is the proper term) within a page.  When I followed vlzvl's advice I received nothing until I loaded the getrss.php on its own.  That was to be expected though as it has not received data from the rss.php page.  The expected stuff aside I received a Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Empty string supplied as input in getrss.php on line 43  Which is the following

$xmlDoc->load($xml);

Comment: @Barmar I have tried rewriting the if($q== and $xml= in several different variations if('".$q."') {
$xml=('" . $row['info2'] . "');    ect.  All to no avail...  What do you see wrong as my quoting problem exactly?

Comment: This is an attempt to add functionality to a database driven dropdown system that I patched together a little bit ago.  I can post that as its fully functional and may give you a better understanding of what exactly I am trying to do here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select name="users" onchange="showRSS(this.value)">
```

Answer (score 0):

These lines:

```
if($q=='" . $row['id'] . "') {
    $xml=('" . $row['info2'] . "');
}
```

Is invalid syntax. It's the string

```
"  $row[
```

followed by the identifier

```
id
```

followed by the string

```
] . "
```

You can't have a sequence like that, you need some kind of operator between them. You apparently meant to concatenate something with those double quotes and dots, but since they're inside the single quote they're just literal characters.

It should be:

```
if ($q == $row['id']) {
    $xml = $row['info2'];
}
```

The code as you wrote it shouldn't even run, I don't know how you're getting error messages about the call to `DOMDocument::load()`. There's no need to call this on the values retrieved from the database if you're not using them as input into another query.

I don't understand why you need that `if` test, though. Your SQL only retrieves rows where `id = $q`, so that test will always succeed.

Also, `mysqli_real_escape_string()` should only be used to escape variables that you're going to substitute into SQL statements.

Comment: Negative sir this does not work :-/  Many thanks though.

Comment: I am unsure how exactly to check what var_dump($row['info2'}) would show.  

I have used this method calling a dataset from a drop down in a parent page to a nested page so I could alter it in a text forms located in the nested page.  I am now trying to get a specific page to load  based upon the dropdown driven data from a parent page.

Comment: You can view the raw output from the script in Response section of the Network tab of Developer Tools/Firebug

Comment: Okie just installed firebug.

Comment: I am getting an error of 
ReferenceError: showUser is not defined

so let me look through and see if I left some scraps from the last project.  once its working I will clean up all the unneed stuff

Comment: Just installed it?!? How have you been debugging your javascript until now?

Comment: Well I need to go to sleep good sir.  Thank you for your help, may I contact you at another time.  Have a good evening

Comment: <select name="users" onchange="showRSS(this.value)"> works its a change from showUser(didnt transition everything fully)

Comment: You need to make both fixes.

Comment: You are correct.  I also need to convert over to PDO.  I marked it down on my list of backend things to do once I am done with all the pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Working code, still needs to swap mysqli for pdo

rss.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showRSS(str) {
  if (str.length==0) {
    document.getElementById("rssOutput").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("rssOutput").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","getrss.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>


<form method="post" action="rss.php">
<select name="users" onchange="showRSS(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","table");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['uname'] . "</option>";
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="rssOutput">RSS Display</div>
</body>
</html>
```

getrss.php

```
<?php

ini_set("display_errors",1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

//get the q parameter from URL
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","table");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id ='".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {


$id = $row['id'];

$xml = $row['info2'];


$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);

//get elements from "<channel>"
$channel=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);
$channel_title = $channel->getElementsByTagName('title')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_link = $channel->getElementsByTagName('link')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_desc = $channel->getElementsByTagName('description')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

//output elements from "<channel>"
echo("<p><a href='" . $channel_link
  . "'>" . $channel_title . "</a>");
echo("<br>");
echo($channel_desc . "</p>");

//get and output "<item>" elements
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');
for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++) {
  $item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item_link=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item_desc=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  echo ("<p><a href='" . $item_link
  . "'>" . $item_title . "</a>");
  echo ("<br>");
  echo ($item_desc . "</p>");
}
}
?>
```